# Selenium IDE xpaths changing by one number

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I'll try explaining this as best I can. I have several spots where I have to use xpaths in my Selenium IDE tests. Usually they work just fine, but sometimes I will try running a test only to have it fail at the xpath. When I inspect the element with Firebug, I discover that the xpath has changed by 1 number.

```
Example: starts as //body/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]
```

but then it changes to `//body/div[3]/div/ul/li[3]`

I tried asking the developer we have that knows Selenium, but he had no idea.  I was thinking perhaps the item was maybe moved on the page (we're still going through a lot of changes), but when I experimented with that today, nothing changed except for me logging out and then back in.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to write xpaths that goes from root (body) through all nodes to the desired element. It's difficult to read and introduces the problems like the one you are having right now. So the solution would be to write an xpath in a different way that is less dependent from page structure. We will need to see your HTML to help with that.

Comment: As tends to happen, after seeing this happen for the past few weeks and finally asking here, we found the answer today. The page has hidden divs that were causing the page to keep adding to that first number when the right conditions were met. Sorry, I'm not very technical, but that's the gist of what the developer said. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: very good link when using xpaths http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html